# Chunking stream into data chunks using Node.js

Tags: node.js, stream

I am trying to chunk a file into data chunks. I found [that link](https://www.npmjs.org/package/chunking-streams) does the job beautifully but when I use the above library in the following manner:

```
var in = fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/try.html'),
        chunker = new SizeChunker({
            chunkSize: 2048
        }),
        output;

    chunker.on('chunkStart', function(id, done) {
        output = fs.createWriteStream('./output-' + id);
        console.log("Chunkstart!");
        console.log("Input: "+in.length);
        done();
    });

    chunker.on('chunkEnd', function(id, done) { 
        output.end();
        console.log("Chunkend!");
        done();
    });

    chunker.on('data', function(dat) {
        console.log("Writing chunk to output!")
        output.write(dat.chunk);
        console.log(dat.chunk);
    });

    input.pipe(chunker);
```

But I am getting this error :

> ```
>     _stream_writable.js:201
>      var len = state.objectMode ? 1 : chunk.length;
>                                     ^
>     TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:201:41)
>     at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
>     at SizeChunker.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Documents/chunk.js:16:15)
>     at SizeChunker.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>     at SizeChunker.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
>     at SizeChunker.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
>     at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
>     at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
>     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
>     at SizeChunker.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
> ```

Also, in.length is undefined when displayed using console.log(). Can anyone please help me resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you listen for `data` on the `chunker` stream, the `dat` argument has no property `chunk`. You can read on the chunking-stream readme the following:

> Each data chunk is an object with the following fields:
>
> id: number of chunk (starts from 1) data: Buffer with data

You can do something like this instead:

```
chunker.on('data', function(dat) {
  console.log("Writing chunk to output!")
  output.write(dat.data);
  console.log(dat);
});
```

Also, `in` is a stream and has no `length` property defined.

Comment: Thank you. Readme fixed in v0.0.4 (pushed, published)

Comment: @Olegas: The chunkSize parameter does not seem to work really. Even when I changed it, there is no effect on the output files. How to fix that?

Comment: @RAhul registered https://github.com/Olegas/node-chunking-streams/issues/2. Will fix today.

Comment: @RAhul fixed this. Note - now chunk number is started from 0 (changed in docs also)

Comment: @Olegas: There is still another issue that I found. After every 16 chunks there is a chunk of 0 bytes. Please fix this issue as well.